# Is there a separate GPS chip in the iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, gps

My mapping apps in my iPhone 6 have become almost completely useless.  Both Google Maps and Apple Maps are unable to track my location with any kind of accuracy, often placing me on side streets or not updating my position at all after the initial setup.

However when I kill those apps and use Find My IPhone app, it almost always locates me exactly, and very quickly.  This leads me to believe they are using a different circuit or method to find my phone as opposed to the mapping apps that fail.

My question, and I've seen opposing opinions, is does my IPhone have a separate GPS chip that could possibly be replaced and restoring my mapping functionality.  **OR** has anyone found a reliable way to reset and restore these mapping failures (I've tried everything I can find online with no luck)?

Comment: gps function needs to be working to make telephone calls

Comment: What level of inaccuracy are you seeing? Like, 215 feet or 6 miles?

Comment: @grooveplex it varies up to maybe a mile on occasion.  Even when the location is accurate, though, it often is frozen.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. That's pretty serious, then.